# Website appearing and then disappearing automatically after a few days on Google My Business

Tags: seo, google, google-my-business

I am facing a rather weird problem with Google My Business. I am having my music school listed in Google My Business. I provided my website in the listing mentioned.

Now the problem is that, my website is displayed for some days and then gets removed automatically, leaving behind only the “Add a website” link. Then when I re-apply, within seconds it is displayed again. And then again after a few days, like magic, it’s gone...

Why is this happening? What did I do wrong?

P.S. I would like to admit that I never tried anything to game the system.

Comment: Please anyone...